# AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'get_descendant_count' | django-mptt

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-mptt, django-1.11

Can someone help me to fix next problem. I use [django-mptt](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt) application in my Django project. I want to make tree of related users. For this task I decided to create `Profile` model with next code.

```
from mptt.models import MPTTModel, TreeForeignKey

class Profile(MPTTModel):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    referral = models.OneToOneField(
        Referral,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    parent = TreeForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True, blank=True,
        related_name='children'
    )

class MPTTMeta:
    order_insertion_by = ['user']
```

**Problem**: In views.py I want to change parent field value of Profile object but has next error.

**ERROR:**

```
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\Project\project_venv\lib\site-packages\mptt\models.py", line 209, in get_ordered_insertion_target
    if parent is None or parent.get_descendant_count() > 0:
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'get_descendant_count'
```

**views.py:**

```
print(self.created_user) # return correct value

profile = Profile.objects.get(id=5)
profile.parent = self.created_user
profile.save()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't define the `parent` as pointing to another class. That wouldn't make sense; the point of a tree is that you have a hierarchical set of items of the same type.

Your `parent` TreeForeignKey needs to point to `"self"`, and you need to pass it an instance of `Profile`, not `User`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Can I ask you one more question? If I want to show a tree of related profiles for a specific profile what kind of queryset it must be? I tried to use `Profile.objects.all()` but it show me all profiles in the system. I tried to use `Profile.objects.get(id=5).get_children()` but it show me first level childrens without deepening. I want to show all childrens with all levels of specific profile. How to make it?

Comment: From documentation I found `.get_descendants()` method to last my task.